# Calcarea Phosphorica 6x

Tags: newborn

Many of my friends and even some relatives are suggesting to give **Calcarea Phosphorica 6x** (homeopathic medicine) to my baby (4.2 months old). I have few questions regarding it.

1. Should we give it? Is it really mandatory?
2. If yes then when should we start?
3. After reading about it, I reckon its a type of salt so does it really depends on a brand for example Dr.Reckeweg (below) or any brand would suffice?

[image]

Will appreciate any help or guidance in this.

Thanks

Comment: Requesting medical advice is off-topic here. You'll have to contact a doctor.

Comment: @Erik: homeopathic remedies aren't medicine, though. There's a simple answer which is a resounding no, this is of no use for anything.

Comment: @dxh if that's the stance of this site, I'd totally agree with you that homeopathy doesn't do anything, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: @Erik This site doesn't have a "stance" on any issues except its scope. However like the rest of Stack Exchange it does value evidence-based answers, and the evidence on homoeopathy is very clear.

Answer (score 12):

[Homeopathy is a waste of money](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/homeopathy/)

It has no effect besides placebo. You never need it, for anything.